# Regex to parse the "Accept" header

Tags: regex, http, coldfusion, header

I'm working on a REST API. The client is using the Accept header in their request to send in stuff like

- `...application/vnd.mywebsite+json; version=1...` or
- `...application/vnd.mywebsite+xml; version=2...`.

Currently, I am parsing the headers and picking out the media type and version to serve with string functions:

- `json` and `1`
- `xml` and `2`

I was wondering if I could do that faster with a regex.

How can I pull out the format and version from an "Accept" header in the request? I suppose, I would need to make 2 regex calls to get this done, and that's okay.

**Update :**

Using the answer below, I tried extracting those using `ColdFusion`, but the pattern just matches the whole string.

Ideally, I want an array of 2 elements, ie `['json', '1']`. Any ideas ?

```
<cfscript>
    arrTitles = reMatch(
        "application/vnd.website\+([A-Za-z]+);\s*version=(\d+)",
        "application/vnd.website+json; version=2"
    );

    writedump(arrTitles);
</cfscript>
```

Please refer this [runnable example](http://trycf.com/gist/916e30f382fba677825c/acf11?theme=monokai).

Comment: *header in the request* Can you be more specific? What is the context for this "request"?

Comment: This is for a REST API. So the client is using the `Accept` header in their request to send in stuff like `application/vnd.mywebsite+json; version=1` or `application/vnd.mywebsite+xml; version=2` as part of that. I am parsing that out and picking out the media type and version to serve, but I was wondering if I could do that faster with a regex.

Comment: *I am parsing that out and picking out the media type and version to serve* Okay.  For next time, please include your current code as well. Questions that do not indicate what was already attempted (and results, error message, etcetera), [closed as off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions) and down voted.

Comment: Typo: That should have read "...*tend* to be closed as off-topic..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use something simple like this:

```
application/vnd.mywebsite\+([A-Za-z]+);\s*version=(\d+)
```

The type (json or xml) would be in capturing group 1, the version in group 2.

You can see it working [here](http://regexr.com/3c7e1).

Comment: What if there is stuff before and after? Like:
`something=eeffe; application/vnd.mywebsite+json; version=1; else=rerhr`

Comment: @EvagorasCharalambous - Shouldn't matter, as written the regex doesn't have any anchors for begin / end string. Paste your example into the link in my answer, you'll see it only matches the middle part.

Comment: So I am trying to get those out using ColdFusion, and the pattern just matches the whole string. Any ideas? http://trycf.com/gist/916e30f382fba677825c/acf11?theme=monokai . Ideally, I want an array of 2 elements, one with the value 'json' and another with '1'.

Comment: I don't think CF can do multiple group matching, so I will need to do each one separately. I am marking this as correct since it seems to have the correct regex - I just need to separate them.

Comment: *the pattern just matches the whole string* Unfortunately reMatch's handling of back references is rather useless IMO. So - yes - you will need to separate them.  What about using nickb's expression with reReplace instead? After you have validated the header, use reReplace to remove the extraneous text. Then use list functions to return an array with the matching elements? http://trycf.com/gist/b0f58e6f64333292071f/acf11?theme=monokai

Comment: *RE: What if there is stuff before and after?* Just noticed that. Here is a new version that should work: http://trycf.com/gist/585fc4863179825934d6/acf11?theme=monokai

Comment: @Leigh perfect! Exactly what I needed!